# Container as tooltip doesn't show contents

Tags: python, ipywidgets, bqplot

I'm creating a scatterplot and want to show some information in a tooltip.

The following works perfectly:

```
import bqplot as bqp
import ipywidgets as ipw

xSc = bqp.LinearScale()
ySc = bqp.LinearScale()

tt = ipw.Label("A")
def hover_handler(self, content):
    tt.value = str(content)

s = bqp.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[1, 2, 3], scales=dict(x=xSc, y=ySc),
                tooltip=tt)
s.on_hover(hover_handler)
bqp.Figure(marks=[s])
```

(there's no axes and whatnot to keep the code short)

Hovering over each point shows its `content` just fine.

[image]

However, I don't want to simply show the raw content. Instead, I want to show it in tabular form (but the default `bqp.Tooltip` isn't sufficient for my needs).

However, if I wrap the label in a `ipw.VBox`, the tooltip becomes a tiny vertical sliver. Adding a `min_width` and `min_height` increases the size of the tooltip, but there's no content (even though `tt` was created with a default value). If I make a separate call to display the VBox alone, that version appears normally (even without defining the layout) and even updates when moving the mouse over the points.

```
import bqplot as bqp
import ipywidgets as ipw
from IPython.display import display

xSc = bqp.LinearScale()
ySc = bqp.LinearScale()

tt = ipw.Label("A")
vb = ipw.VBox(children=[tt], layout=ipw.Layout(min_width='100px', min_height='100px'))
display(vb)
def hover_handler(self, content):
    tt.value = str(content)

s = bqp.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[1, 2, 3], scales=dict(x=xSc, y=ySc),
                tooltip=vb)
s.on_hover(hover_handler)
bqp.Figure(marks=[s])
```

[image]

What do I need to do for the tooltip to appear correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you are trying you achieve you would be better served with an `Output` widget as a tooltip, and then create the widgets you need and display them using the output widget as a context manager.

If you want to see what additional information could be presented, try printing `content` within your `hover_handler` function.

```py
    import bqplot as bqp
    import ipywidgets as ipw
    from IPython.display import display, clear_output

    xSc = bqp.LinearScale()
    ySc = bqp.LinearScale()


    out = ipw.Output()

    def hover_handler(self, content):
        out.clear_output()
        with out:
            label = ipw.Label(content['data']['name'])
            display(label)

    s = bqp.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[1, 2, 3], scales=dict(x=xSc, y=ySc),
                    tooltip=out)
    s.on_hover(hover_handler)
    bqp.Figure(marks=[s])
```

To display a table of information, you probably need an `ipy.HTML` widget which you can use to pass a HTML table. I sometimes use pandas for this, with the df.to_html() method.

Comment: Yeah, my current workaround is precisely an `ipy.HTML` widget which I hardcoded with a table. I was unaware of `df.to_html`, will check it out, and will see how the tooltip looks when wrapped in an `ipw.Output` (don't have access to the code today).

Comment: This isn't working, unfortunately. I just get a blank (but non-zero sized) tooltip, even if I change the label to simply `ipw.Label('A')`. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVYvT.png).

Comment: Which version of ipywidgets and bqplot are you working with?

Comment: ipywidgets 7.3.2 and bqplot 0.11.4

Comment: I'm using ipywidgets 7.4.2 and bqplot 0.11.4. I'm using Chrome browser, not sure if that makes a difference.